# How to specify language dialect in \lstline option?

Tags: listings, brackets, optional-arguments

First, here is some code that works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstinline[language=algol,keywordstyle=\color{blue}]{int a}
\end{document}
```

This uses the `algol 68` dialect and it works fine. Now I am going to replace `int` with `integer` in the code which requires `algol 60` dialect for proper syntax highlighting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstinline[language=[60]algol,keywordstyle=\color{blue}]{integer a}
\end{document}
```

Obviously this does not work due to `[...]` within `[...]`. I get this error:

```
Runaway argument?
{integer a} \end {document}
```

How do I specify the language dialect within `\lstline` option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeX sees the `]` in `[60]algol` as the closing bracket for the optional argument so, putting it differently, what it understood was that the optional argument was `language=[60` and chaos ensued. Hide the `[60]algol` inside a pair of `{`...`}`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstinline[language={[60]algol},keywordstyle=\color{blue}]{integer a}
\end{document}
```